# List of function of subset of a list

Tags: python, list, function

So I've got a list, say, L = [0,1,2,3]; I would like to apply a function (with two arguments) to each of the values of the sublists [0,1], [1,2], [2,3] and in turn produce another list of the new values.
I.e. [f(0,1), f(1,2), f(2,3)]

I've looked all over and cannot seem to find an answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,
Dave

Edit: I'm using Python.

Comment: Is this for a particular programming language?

Comment: `zipWith f list (tail list)`, if you can use Haskell.

Comment: My apologies, yes, I'm using python.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = [f(*args) for args in zip(L, L[1:])]
```

Or:

```
result = map(f, L[:-1], L[1:])
```

A lazy version using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) functions that generate results on demand:

```
it = starmap(f, izip(L, islice(L, 1, None)))
```

Or:

```
it = imap(f, L, islice(L, 1, None))
```

Or if `L` were an arbitrary iterable:

```
a, b = tee(L)
it = imap(f, a, islice(b, 1, None))
```